# object oriented design in java | Libgdx methods

Tags: java, android, libgdx, organization, ooad

This question is relatively easy to answer but i don't really know the answer as i have no real experience with java or libgdx.

**Question:** I would like to know the most effiecent way to orginize code in java, i have a strong background in php and in my php projects i would use several different php files (think of it as a class) and just reference it in my main page using either **"`include 'filename'; or require 'filename';` "** . I would keep my header.php, content.php and footer.php completely separate and just reference it. This was a very nice method for me as it really kept my code organized.

What i want to know is if there is an easy way to do this in java/libgdx? i am currently making an android application and as you may know there are life cycles such as create(); render(); resize(); etc.

What i had in mind was to put each cycle e.g. create(); into a class of its own and use `extends` in my main class. Will this even work?

Thanks for any help in advance guys, its really bugging me to have so much of my code in one main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very abstract, and you can read lots of books or articles about OOP, design patterns and code styling, so I will just give few practical tips:

1. You can use MVC pattern. Create three packages `yourpackage.view`, `yourpackage.model`, `yourpackage.controller` and split your classes by this model.
2. You can create package `yourpackage.utiles` and put there all classes with only `static` methods, which are used in all your app.
3. Don't put too much code into one class, `Java` is very objected oriented. Very simple example: you have game with 4 screens. You should create parent `Screen class`, 4 `classes` which will be extended from `Screen` for every screen and `class ScreenManager` which will change screens.
4. In game dev `Singleton` is very useful pattern. You can use it for GraphicMangaer, charcter progress holding, dpad controller, etc.

About your question, there is no reason to put `create()` method into your classes, constructor is enough. What you can do is to create `draw()` method in every class which draws something and put there all logic of drawing. Then you can just call `draw()` methods of your classes in your screen `render()` method.